# VIsual Studio: Avoid console from popping up and integrate it into IDE instead

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

In Visual Studio when I run a program, the console pops up as a separate window. Many other IDEs, such as CLion or Eclipse integrate that console in the IDE. Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio as well? I feel this is a very basic requirement but I cannot find any such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No not really, tough why would you need it like that? If you are making an app with some graphical library and you down want it to show up you can disable it in the project options.

Comment: 'No not really' isnt that an answer?

Comment: _why would you need it like that_ cause when you're debugging something, one usually has to keep their IDE window visible, and it's ridiculous having to also have a separate console window when an IDE could easily have it in the IDE itself alongside watches etc

Comment: But you can always disable it, can't you? Tough i would u derstand you if you still need the i formation written in the console.